# How to reverse engineer from existing database schema

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database schema say test with some tables and inter dependencies. Now using MySQL workbench i can reverse engineer to get the create schema script.

How is it possible to achieve the same using mysqldump command i.e., get the create schema and the foreign key references should be maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make mysql dump. It will contain SQL data definition statements.

Comment: I dont want data. I just want the table structure. Can this be done?

Comment: you can skip data during making dump, this option is available :)

Comment: Can u also post the command line statement for the same

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html see option --no-data